# Scrape instagram liker with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, instagram-api

I have a number of Instagram post addresses, and I want to scrape the usernames of people who liked these posts based on this video.

[video link](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=d2GBO_QjRlo)

Does Instagram have any limitations for this task, and is it possible for them to restrict the IP? Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance.
I'm completely unfamiliar with the topic of APIs and relation to selenium.
Is it possible for you to recommend a resource that provides step-by-step instructions on what I should do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Scraping data from Instagram using tools like Selenium is against [Instagram's terms of service](https://help.instagram.com/581066165581870), and it can result in your account being banned. Instagram can restrict or block access from IP addresses that exhibit suspicious or abusive behavior, such as excessive scraping or bot-like activity.If you need access to Instagram data for legitimate purposes, you should explore using their [official API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I'm completely unfamiliar with the topic of APIs and relation to selenium. Is it possible for you to recommend a resource that provides step-by-step instructions on what I should do? Thank you.

Comment: I'm certain it won't be hard to find resources on using APIs with Selenium on YouTube and elsewhere, however I'd suggest getting started with, [official selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation).